# PHP7 - nusoap - nusoap_client has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to use `nusoap` on `Laravel 5.3` with `PHP7`. But when ill try to install it with `composer` from that package:

https://github.com/codecasts/nusoap-php7 (v.0.9.6)

It still returns me:

> ErrorException in class.soapclient.php line 26: Methods with the same
>   name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of
>   PHP; nusoap_client has a deprecated constructor

Ill cleared the cache, but all with no success. Anyone has successfully implemented `nusoap` in `Laravel` with `PHP7` ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the code you linked? It has proper constructor name (`__construct`), so it shouldn't throw that error.

Comment: Of course. I installed it with composer, and it says me that it is correct installed. Also checked my vendor plugins. Thats why i am not sure what cause the problem (and asking is someone has it successfully installed) - so youre working with nosuap on php7?

Comment: To be sure, break that file you think you are using (for example change word `class` to `start_working_damnit` ;) and check if you get parse error. If not, then you'are not using this file. Other than that I don't have a clue.

Comment: Already tried, everything seems to be correct ;) - but thanks for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I've found on GitHub a new version of the nusoap.php file that you will have to copy in your actual NuSoap folder. The deprecated constructor has been rewritten.

Here is the link where you'll be able to get the file:
https://github.com/econea/nusoap

Comment: I'm maintainer of econea/nusoap and I'm able to help you with everything. Just create an issue or something if you like.

Comment: I'm trying to port my nusoap code from PHP 5.2 to PHP 7 can't find in the link the nusoap.php you Sebastien said

Comment: On the GitHub repository, some refactoring has been made in the develop branch. In particular the nusoap.php file has been splitted in different classes. But if you look at the previous commits in the develop branch or at the master branch (https://github.com/econea/nusoap/blob/master/src/nusoap.php) you will be able to file the nusoap.php file.